# interstitial test iAds not work in iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, iad, interstitial

Only in `iOS 8.4` (tested on both device and emulator).

When loading interstitial `iAd` I'm receiving this message:

> Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3
>   "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable"
> UserInfo=0x........
> {ADInternalErrorCode=3, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Adinventory unavailable, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain}

When using `iOS 9` (both device and emulator) it works correctly.

The adBanner is working in both iOS 8 and 9

Some suggestion ?

Comment: How are you implementing your interstitial?

Comment: I'm trying in both ways (old one used before iOS 7 and the new method). In both occurs the same problem. They work ok in iOS 9, and presents "Ad inventory unavailable" in iOS 8.  
Old method:  
interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];  
interstitial.delegate = self;  
  
[interstitial presentFromViewController:localViewController];  
  
New method:  
[UIViewController prepareInterstitialAds];  
  
[self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];  
  
I’m thinking Apple is not serving Ads (or test Ads) for iOS 8.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue, i'm having the exact same issue however, once in a very blue moon i am getting an interstitial to load. Although the main iAD splash screen doesn't appear its a black screen, tapping on this does load the advert correctly though!

Comment: Apple is not accepting new apps with iAds.

Comment: Are you sure, i've read that they are just shutting down the part of the network that allows developers to create their own adverts, not the whole iAD network: http://www.engadget.com/2016/01/15/apple-iad-shutdown-june-30th/

Comment: I'm sure. I received this information from an internal. And I submitted an app with iAds, it was approved but iAds didn't appeared many days after publishing. My other older apps continues showing iAds normally. I changed to Admob.

Comment: Thanks Rogerup, that has cleared up a few issues, its pretty poor that apple aren't forthcoming with the information regarding their advert network.